# Get directive element and template element both for compiling directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive which itself can be inserted into the template, like this:

```
(function() {
  function FormInputDirective() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        label: "@"
      },
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        //tElement.find(".input-container").append(directiveElement);

        var link = function($scope, element, attrs) {
          //....
        };
        return link;
      },
      templateUrl: 'form-input.html'
    }
  }
  angular.module("mainApp", []).directive("formInput", [FormInputDirective]);
})();
```

template:

```
<div class="form-group input-container">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <!-- where the directive element to be inserted -->
</div>
```

usage:

```
<input type="number" ... form-input label="Name:" />
<input type="text" ....  form-input label="address:" min-length=... />
<textrea ................form-input label="Description" .......
....
```

expected result:

```
<div class="form-group input-container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="number" ... form-input label="Name:" />
</div>
<div class="form-group input-container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" ... form-input label="Address:" />
</div>
```

..................
[Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UTejZs0lRvLVoCciTPyC?p=preview)

However if I want to make it work, I will have to get both the `directive element` and the `template element` which I have no idea at the moment. Since once the directive have a `template`, then the first argument passed to the `compile` function will be the `template element, I can not find a way to get the`directive element`.

And I also know I can use `ng-tranclude`, however I will have to write extra elements like this:

```
<any-dir>
   <input ...... />
</any-dir>
```

I want to avoid this.

Is this possible?

Comment: why do you want to do this ? Why not have a child directive that you place in the template from the start?

Comment: As I said, I do not want to add the extra wrap element, since I have almost 50+  fields to be filled in the form.

Comment: Well you would still use the parent directive (only the template would have the child directive). So you would still have <input type="number" parent-directive label="Name: "/>

Comment: @sirrocco: You mean define the `input` element in the template from the start? But the to be filled inputs are not sure, I may add `input` `select` `textarea` and etc. See my update.

Comment: So one can not use the `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tranclude : 'element'`

[From angular docs :](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> 'element' - transclude the whole of the directive's element including
>   any directives on this element that defined at a lower priority than
>   this directive. When used, the template property is ignored.

[a working demo using your exemple](http://plnkr.co/edit/JmHWhXiTSwhDzm2ONJGn?p=preview)

Comment: exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: However I found that the root element of the template will add all the attributes like `class` `ng-model` from the directive ifself, check this:http://plnkr.co/edit/icEzd9QUN30KwDlHZ9Wm?p=preview